# How to prevent new VS Code window from launching for remote ssh connections

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

When connecting to a remote machine using VS Code Remote SSH this act always opens a new VS Code Window.  Is there a way to change this behavior to use the existing open window?  Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is. VSCode needs to re-initialize a lot of things in the remote session so it has to be restarted.

Comment: Will submit a feature request for this.  Perhaps a way can be found.

Comment: It is possible to drag the tab from new window to existing local workbench but having two simultaneous remote connections in the same window doesn't work [yet].

Comment: I have the same problem, open always a new window, and cannot put it together my workspace opened previously

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a separate command for this.

You need to do `Remote-SSH: Connect Current Window to Host...`

instead of `Remote-SSH: Connect to Host...`

---

[image: VSCode screenshot]

Comment: This does not work for me. Latest 1.7 vscode no matter what I do, even from no workspace, nothing, when i choose remote connection it *always* spawns a new window.

Comment: I just updated and still works for me on [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/davetapley/ce12f74f1824886ccabbacd2e7d292cf/raw/d6ac93f0858be9e77af5a158c8f7cbd7e0201111/code). Maybe [open a bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/new/choose) to see if OS specific?

Comment: I won't delete my comment but my answer was not to expect an open project to instantiate a new remote ssh session in the same vscode process, so a new process is required by design in my use case.

Comment: It does not work: it is true that it uses the same window, but before doing so it removes anything open. It has the same effect as closing the current window and creating a new one.

Answer (score -2):

vscode open terminal / PowerShell

input：ssh user@hostname  and Enter password

Comment: While many wrongly gave this post negative votes, this is why I was here. Thank you my friend for the solution. Shame on those who voted negatively.

Comment: This solution just accesses the remote host through a terminal... it's getting downvoted because the question is asking about launching a remote repository through the Remote-SSH extension, which opens a new window by "default".